# Java object heap, could not create the JVM

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I've got an heap space problem when running my java program using *Eclipse* and *Maven*, I've made a few search and I've already created MAVEN_OPTS, changed my arguments in the Maven run configurations and in the Java options of *Eclipse* but it still doesn't work...

Does someone have an idea?

Comment: What exactly are the values in the Run Configuration/VM Arguments? I ask this because it sometimes happens to me that I specify -Xmx32 instead of -Xmx32g, which results in above error. Furthermore, if you run on Unix, make sure your data segment sizte is not limited.

Comment: It would also be interesting to hear how it works in the command line, i.e. **without** anything inbetween you and your program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be Eclipse that needs more memory. Edit eclipse.ini and change the -xmx value. It's also a good idea to change -XX:MaxPermSize.

```
-Xmx1024m
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

[Source](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_increase_the_heap_size_available_to_Eclipse?)

Comment: I've done this and it's still not working. Here is what I have in eclipse.ini : 
`--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M`
`-Xms40m`
`-Xmx1024m`

Comment: Sorry for the late validation. It was indeed the Eclipse conf, it needed some adjustements. Thank's a lot

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you ask the VM to use either more memory than you have in your machine or more than is supported by the JVM. If you are using a 32bit JVM, consider switching to a 64bit JVM.

Comment: Well, I'm already using a 64bit JVM and it's the first time I have this problem, considering I'm using quite the same code as usual with a few modifications when I've updated the source with SVN